# Keep https:// on both domain and subdomain but remove www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to find a way to retain `https://` on both my domain and subdomain whilst removing the `www.` from the URL.

**Examples:**

```
URL 1: http://www.mywebsite.co.uk
Redirect 1: https://mywebsite.co.uk

URL 2: http://test.mywebsite.co.uk
Redirect 2: https://test.mywebsite.co.uk

URL 3: http://mywebsite.co.uk
Redirect 3: https://mywebsite.co.uk

URL 4: http://www.test.mywebsite.co.uk
Redirect 4: https://test.mywebsite.co.uk
```

I have come across multiple attempts to try and combat this issue on Stack Overflow and received bother Apache and PHP to script into my site to fix, but they always seem to come with additional issues.

**Current .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mywebsite\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Whilst this is helping my retain SSL on my subdomains, I can still access my main domains and subdomains by prepending `www.` on the URL. This is not the desired effect I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: This still allows www. on subdomains, and also because I have rewrite rules above this now, it now redirect www.mywebsite.com/dashboard/ to https://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=dashboard which crashes my single page application using AngularJS.

Comment: This must be placed as first rule below `RewriteEngine` line and you must clear browser cache. Also make sure there is no other rule/code forcing `www` on subdomain.